# What is the temperature under the surface of Mercury?

Tags: temperature, mercury, heat

What is the temperature under the surface of Mercury?  I know at the surface the temperature varies greatly (-297 F to 801 F).  I also realize that the answer would likely depend on depth.  Do we know the temperature at any depth, except the surface?  I also realize the temperature may vary based on latitude.  I am mainly looking to see if there might be an ideal location / depth for a colony on Mercury for my game Planetary Settlers.

Comment: Are you thinking of just the crust or further down? One would think there'd be some educated guesses out there of the mantle and core temperatures.

Comment: @Kozaky - Mainly just the crust (e.g. anywhere from a few feet to a few miles, wherever the temperature should be mostly stable).

Comment: There's evidence that Mercury has a molten iron-sulfur core.  It has a stable magnetic field about 1% the strength of earth's, probably from a dynamo connected to a molten core.  The core itself could only remain molten from the tidal forces of the sun. I've not found a proposed temperature for that core, but if you had one you could in principle model temperatures at a given depth by assuming an approximately linear relation to achieve thermal equilibrium.  The accuracy of that, or any other model, might be hard to quantify.

Comment: Deeper will generally mean a more stable temperature. Based on Earth experience (caves, mines) I expect a mile deep would be plenty to find near-constant temperature. Somewhere near the poles, you might even find a tolerable temperature. This paper [https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00110923] describes an effort to get detailed data.